# create a table in django and save model to it

Tags: python, django

I am stuck on this stage where I need to save my model to a particular table. I have installed postgres and now I  want to firstly create 2 tables A and B and append instance of model 'modelA' to table 'A' and of 'modelB' to B. I cannot find much on this on googling and stackoverflow in a clear form.

Comment: `A.objects.create(field1=value1, field2=value2)`?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can you also tell whether it creates/update or overwrites the table?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: @VisheshMangla: it creates a new record. That being said, it might be a good idea to start with the official Django tutorial. I think it is quite good in giving the "basics" on how to work with Django, and usually the rest can then be found in the general documentation.

Comment: I didn't know that the answer lied in the polls app. Thanks for that too.

Comment: Yes, I will finish the poll app right away. How can I mark it as resolved or should I delete this post if its a basic one?

Comment: Can you please share with us your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running your migrations, so that the **tables** will be created inside of your DB. This happens in your `models.py` file. Any name you give to the `class` of the table in the `models.py`, it will correspond to the same name, in lowercase and underscores, the table in your **PostgreSQL DB**, except if you want to override it.

Here are some nice and helpful tutorials, about **Django** with **PostgreSQL**:

- [Creating a Django Web Application with a PostgreSQL Database on Windows](https://medium.com/@9cv9official/creating-a-django-web-application-with-a-postgresql-database-on-windows-c1eea38fe294)
- [Step-by-Step Python and Postgres Tutorial with psycopg2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2PDkXviEMD0)

Generic videos about **Django** database and migrations:
* [Python Django Tutorial: Full-Featured Web App Part 5 - Database and Migrations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aHC3uTkT9r8)
* [The Basics of Django Models](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r9kT-jm136Q)

I hope this helps. Please let me know if I helped you!